# Get some objects from array of objects in a document (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get some objects from array of objects in a mongodb document
my document looks something like this

```
{
    movieDetails: {
        movieId: 333,
        movieName: "movie",
    },
    Dates: [
        {
            Date: " 01/07/2021",
            TheaterId: 12,
            Is3D: "false",
        },
        {
            Date: " 09/07/2021",
            TheaterId: 13,
            Is3D: "false",
        },
        {
            Date: " 03/07/2021",
            TheaterId: 12,
            Is3D: "false",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get only the objects where the `movieId` is equal to 333 and `TheaterId` is 12 my result should look like this

```
 [
        {
            Date: " 01/07/2021",
            TheaterId: 12,
            Is3D: "false",
        },
        {
            Date: " 03/07/2021",
            TheaterId: 12,
            Is3D: "false",
        }
 ]
```

I tried this

```
const dates = await Movie.find("movieDetails.movieId": 333).select({ Dates: {$elemMatch: {TheaterId: 12}}});
```

But it returns only the first object if anyone can help me with this I will be very grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`$elemMatch` docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/):

> The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the $elemMatch condition.

So you can use this aggregation pipeline using `$filter` into a `$project` stage like this:

```
Movie.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "movieDetails.movieId": 333
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "movieDetails": 1,
      "Dates": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$Dates",
          "as": "d",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$d.TheaterId",
              12
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CphJlbiC4wy)

Or this another pipeline (I prefer using `$filter`)

```
Movie.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "movieDetails.movieId": 333
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$Dates"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "Dates.TheaterId": 12
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "movieDetails": {
        "$first": "$movieDetails"
      },
      "Dates": {
        "$push": "$Dates"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B0Pu78dyByl)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [the doc for `.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) since it seems you are using it incorrectly.

One way you can achieve this is to use `.find()` to find the movie with the ID you want, then [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `Dates` from that object to return just the ones with your `TheaterId`

here is an example

```js
const movies = [{
  movieDetails: {
    movieId: 333,
    movieName: "movie",
  },
  Dates: [{
      Date: " 01/07/2021",
      TheaterId: 12,
      Is3D: "false",
    },
    {
      Date: " 09/07/2021",
      TheaterId: 13,
      Is3D: "false",
    },
    {
      Date: " 03/07/2021",
      TheaterId: 12,
      Is3D: "false",
    }
  ]
}]

function findMovieTimesByTheater(movieID, theaterID) {
  const movie = movies.find(movie => movie.movieDetails.movieId === movieID);

  if (typeof movie === "undefined") {
    console.log(`movieID: ${movieID} not found`);
    return [];
  }

  return movie.Dates.filter(date => date.TheaterId === theaterID);
}

const times = findMovieTimesByTheater(333, 12);
console.log(times);
```

Comment: my question was about document in mongoose not about objects in js apparently I did not explain my question well I edited the question it seems to me that now it is clearer